# Impossible to delete Facebook Objects

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to delete an object created by a story, but I'm getting the following error :

```
(#100) Cannot delete object not created via the API
```

I used the FB.api in javascript to create a story with news.reads (works), I can delete the story with the ID too. But the object created for the story still exists, I can see it in the Graph API, but cannot delete it.

I want to fix this issue because if I try to create a story with the same article link, if I change the content (the same link refers to a new article), facebook will keep the old settings (title, image and description don't change).

Comment: Well then why not just use a different URL for a new story? (After a story has been published a certain amount of times, you can’t change it any more anyways.) And imagine users finding older posts from stories you created – do you want them to find something totally different when they click on the link?

Answer (score 0):

You can force facebook to re-scrape your site when you use `scrape=true` in your next call:

```
FB.api(
    '/',
    'post',
    {id: <your article url>, scrape: 'true'},
    <your callback function>
);
```